# Once I call DynamicCapture how can I externally retrieve the signature

Tags: wacom

So I have some code that calls the dynamic capture method.  I then can get the user's input etc.  My question is:  How can I interrupt the dynamic capture externally.  e.g. Teller sends the sign request, member signs -- then the teller want to manually retrieve the signature (because the user isn't clicking on OK, or perhaps they want to abort the signature).  How can I interrupt the dynamic capture?  Everything I've tried has failed so far.

```
DynamicCapture dc = new DynamicCapture();
int rc = dc.capture(sigCtl, who, why, null, null); // dc.capture(sigCtl, "who", "why", null, null);
if(rc == 0) {
    System.err.println("signature captured successfully\n");
    String fileName = "signature.jpg";
    SigObj sig = sigCtl.signature();
    sig.extraData("AdditionalData", "CaptureImage.java Additional Data");
    int flags = SigObj.outputFilename | SigObj.color32BPP | SigObj.encodeData;
    sig.renderBitmap(fileName, 300, 233, "image/png", 0.7f, 0x000000, 0xffffff, 0.5f, 0.0f, flags); //flags are: filename, dimensionX, dimensionY, mimeType, inkWidth, inkColor, inkBackground, paddingX, paddingY
    paintSignature(fileName);
    retrieve();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: Wacom Technical Support

> FireClick **cannot be applied to Dynamic
>   Capture** so there is no way to activate the cancel button from the
>   application. I guess you would have to put some sort of timer in and
>   then exit the application completely if there was no response from the
>   user.

However if **not using DynamicCapture**, and using the **wizCtl** object then you can remotely fire the buttons via: `wizCtl.fireClick(OK_BUTTON_ID);`